# Javascript variable scope with event handler acts weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, dom-events

```
<script>  
            var rotateFlag = 0;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log(rotateFlag);
                dropdown();
                getdown();
            });
            function dropdown(){
                if(rotateFlag===0){
                    $('.comment-box').on('click',function(event){
                        console.log("when rotateFlag is 0", rotateFlag);
                        $(this).css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');
                        rotateFlag = 1; 
                    });
                }
                if(rotateFlag===1){
                    $('.comment-box').on('click',function(event){
                        console.log("when rotateFlag is 1", rotateFlag);
                        $('.comment-box').css('transform','rotate(0deg)');
                        rotateFlag = 0;
                    })
                }
            }
            function getdown(){ 
                $(document).on('click',function(event){

                    if( $(event.target)[0].className !=  'comment-box' && 
                        $(event.target)[0].className != 'dot' ){
                        console.log('getdown');
                        $('.comment-box').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)'); 
                        rotateFlag = 0;
                    }
                })
            }
    <script>  
                <div class="comment-box"> 
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                </div>
```

I tried to transform element div named `comment-box`, 
and I faced one problem that variable `rotateFlag` printed 1 
even in `if(rotateFlag ===0)`. 
It's weird.. 
  look at the code  below:

```
            var rotateFlag = 0;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log(rotateFlag);
                dropdown();
                getdown();
            });
            function dropdown(){
                if(rotateFlag===0){
                    $('.comment-box').on('click',function(event){
                        console.log("when rotateFlag is 0", rotateFlag);
                        $(this).css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');
                        rotateFlag = 1; 
                    });
                }
```

I assigned variable `rotateFlag`, and let button event handles only when
`rotateFlag` has value 1. 
The first time I click 'comment-box' it prints 
    when rotateFlag is 0 0 
however, from twice, it returns like this. 
    when rotateFlag is 0 1

weird .... can't get Ideas why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird.. When you call dropdown function(at the first time), rotateFlag is 0.

```
if(rotateFlag===0){
                $('.comment-box').on('click',function(event){
                    console.log("when rotateFlag is 0", rotateFlag);
                    $(this).css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');
                    rotateFlag = 1; 
                });
            }
```

So above click event is applied always.

If you want to apply another click event, off the click event and call dropdown function when getdown function called.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. 
The weired thing I said is when I call dropdown function at the second time, console.log says rotateFlag is 1...

Comment: I don't understatnd.. dropdown function is called just one time in document ready function... How do you call dropdown function twice..?

Comment: No It's not , function dropdown() will be called by every single click $('.comment-box') because dropdown is inside of  
' document.ready(function(){
})' . 
it means dom will response when click event  occurs

Comment: The above comments I mentioned already has been tested by myself